# Error: Application is crashing, exited with code: 1

Tags: javascript, crash

I tried to run my project but my application crashes when doing so. The application first tries to restart himself a couple of times after crashing.
`meteor npm install --save bcrypt` doesn't help. Other options that I tried and didn't work: `meteor reset` and `npm install`. I added the message I receive in my terminal.

```
    W20200224-15:22:15.791(1)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
    W20200224-15:22:15.794(1)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
    W20200224-15:22:15.795(1)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
    W20200224-15:22:15.795(1)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
    W20200224-15:22:15.798(1)? (STDERR) 
    W20200224-15:22:15.798(1)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
    W20200224-15:22:15.798(1)? (STDERR) 
    W20200224-15:22:15.801(1)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
    W20200224-15:22:15.801(1)? (STDERR) /Users/andriespauwels/MORE/App/therapist/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:192
    W20200224-15:22:15.804(1)? (STDERR)                         throw error;
    W20200224-15:22:15.804(1)? (STDERR)                         ^
    W20200224-15:22:15.804(1)? (STDERR) 
    W20200224-15:22:15.808(1)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: dynamicImportInfo is not defined
    W20200224-15:22:15.809(1)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.dynamic-import.server.js (packages/dynamic-import/server.js:15:13)
    W20200224-15:22:15.809(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
    W20200224-15:22:15.813(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
    W20200224-15:22:15.814(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/andriespauwels/MORE/App/therapist/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/dynamic-import.js:493:15
    W20200224-15:22:15.818(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/andriespauwels/MORE/App/therapist/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/dynamic-import.js:499:3
    W20200224-15:22:15.818(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/andriespauwels/MORE/App/therapist/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
    W20200224-15:22:15.818(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
    W20200224-15:22:15.822(1)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/andriespauwels/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.4_6.1bi6nv.es0j9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    W20200224-15:22:15.822(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/andriespauwels/MORE/App/therapist/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
    W20200224-15:22:15.826(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/andriespauwels/MORE/App/therapist/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:352:5
    => Exited with code: 1
    => Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8855